# implement jqgrid with asp.net webpage using database

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, webforms

I would like to integrate jqGrid in asp.net web page. I got data in JSON format. But when rending the page grid made without data.

My written code given below.

**JqGridExample.aspx**

```
    jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid({

     url: 'GetData.aspx',
     datatype: 'json',
     colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Active', 'Gender'],
     colModel: [
       { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 35, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10} },
       { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150, align: "left", editable: true, size: 100 },
       { name: 'isClosed', index: 'isClosed', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "true:false", formatter: "checkbox"} },
       { name: 'gender', index: 'gender', width: 100, formatter: 'select', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "0:select;1:male;2:female"} }
     ],
     rowNum: 10,
     rowList: [2, 5, 10, 15],
     pager: '#pjmap',
     sortname: 'id',
     sortorder: "desc",
     viewrecords: true,
     jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, cell: "", id: "0" },
     width: 600,
     caption: 'First jqGrid',
     height: '100%', viewrecords: true, fixed: true, gridview: true, loadonce: true
   });

<table id="jsonmap">
</table>
<div id="pjmap">
</div>
```

data Which i got from `getdata.aspx` is

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":5,"rows":[{"Name":"John","Id":1,"Gender":1,"IsClosed":false},{"Name":"Abel","Id":2,"Gender":1,"IsClosed":false},{"Name":"Aaron","Id":3,"Gender":1,"IsClosed":true},{"Name":"Tsion","Id":4,"Gender":2,"IsClosed":true},{"Name":"Mussie","Id":5,"Gender":2,"IsClosed":true}]}
```

On Rendering grid on jqGridExample.aspx data is not displaying.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `name` property in `colModel` which exact corresponds to names in JSON data. So you should change `name: 'id'` to `name: 'Id'`, `name: 'name'` to `name: 'Name'`, `name: 'isClosed'` to `name: 'IsClosed'` and `name: 'gender'` to `name: 'Gender'`. You can remove all `index` properties from `colModel` or make the same changes in all `index` properties.

Additionally you should include `key: true` property in the definition of column `Id` in `colModel`.